# Music play which can convert audio

Tags: multimedia

Is there any player using which i can play and (or) convert music? I mean something like foobar2000 for windows.

Comment: What have you looked at and why doesn't this satisfy your needs? There are plenty of question here regarding audio conversion. Have you looked at them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try **[deadbeef](http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/)**, a lightweight player which is somewhat similar to foobar2000 and has conversion capability (you must have the encoders - lame, flac, etc. - installed)

Screenshot from the deadbeef homepage:
[image: Deadbeef]

It is not in the official repositories, but there's a **PPA** available. To install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:starws-box/deadbeef-player
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install deadbeef
```

Alternatively, you can actually use foobar2000 under Linux using `wine`.

Comment: Thx. I'll try it. I can't say that i like the name of this program, but it seems to be the thing that i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not exactly a player, but, avidemux is a pretty powerful tool for converting processes both for video and audios.

Comment: Thx for information, but i'm looking for program that can at the same time play and to convert music.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try out the Sound Converter, XCFA, soundKonverter. All of which can be installed from the software center.

Comment: Thx for information, but i'm looking for program that can at the same time play and to convert music.